# Круг не перемещается в окне, Canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Круг не перемещается в окне, помогите исправить код.

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint


WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.R = randint(20, 50)
        self.x = randint(self.R, WIDTH - self.R)
        self.y = randint(self.R, HEIGHT - self.R)
        self.dx, self.dy = (+2, +3)
        self.ball_id = canvas.create_oval(self.x - self.R,
                                     self.y - self.R,
                                     self.x + self.R,
                                     self.y + self.R,
                                     fill="black")

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
        if self.x + self.R > WIDTH or self.x - self.R <= 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.y + self.R > HEIGHT or self.y - self.R <= 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

    def show(self):
        canvas.move(self, self.dx, self.dy)


def canvas_click_handler(event):
    print("Hello World! x=", event.x, " y=", event.y)

def tick():
    ball.move()
    ball.show()
    root.after(50, tick)

def main():
    global root, canvas, ball

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry(str(WIDTH) + "x" + str(HEIGHT))
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
    canvas.pack(anchor="nw", fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    canvas.bind('<Button-1>', canvas_click_handler)
    ball = Ball()

    tick()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: У меня всё работает: https://i.imgur.com/TXrvGgD.png

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from random import randint
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas


WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

class Ball(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
        self.R = randint(30, 60)
        self.x = randint(self.R, WIDTH - self.R)
        self.y = randint(self.R, HEIGHT - self.R)
        self.dx, self.dy = (+2, +3)
        
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, bg='blue')
        self.canvas.place(relx=0, rely= 0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.ball_id = self.canvas.create_oval(
            self.x - self.R,
            self.y - self.R,
            self.x + self.R,
            self.y + self.R,
            fill="black"
        )
        self.update()
        
    def update(self):
        if self.x + self.R > WIDTH or self.x - self.R <= 0:
            self.dx = -self.dx
        if self.y + self.R > HEIGHT or self.y - self.R <= 0:
            self.dy = -self.dy

        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy

        self.canvas.coords(
            self.ball_id, 
            self.x - self.R,
            self.y - self.R,
            self.x + self.R,
            self.y + self.R,
        )

        self.after(20, self.update)        
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Ball')
    root.geometry('800x600')
    app = Ball(root)
    app.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @theblackmonkey что не так?